# How to protect content from public users and limit access to certain roles in WordPress 2023?

Tags: user-roles, security, content-restriction, members

There are hundreds of content protection plugins and role managers, however in my current case I need a custom solution.

The customer wants that only "logged in users" are to be able to read articles, while some articles are public and some are only available to certain user roles. Also, titles and excerpts shall always be public.

Within the (custom) theme this is easy to check, however WordPress has a REST API, an RSS feed and more.

So within the theme I check it, but how can I make sure that the contents are not publicly available on the internet?

- disable REST API
- disable RSS
- ... what else?